# Read val() of input inside a div display:none

Tags: jquery, html

I've set up a small website, with a tooltip created with [smallipop](http://projects.sebastianhelzle.net/jquery.smallipop/). I've put an input inside this tooltip, and now I want to do ajax submit,but that's not the problem. The matter is how to get the correct value of the input `#Number`.

I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Mqe/6/) for it.

HTML:

```
<h1>WeTest</h1>
<div>


<span class="test" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:500px;" id="weTrill">
    click me
    <span class="smallipopHint" >
        <div class="weTrillForm">
            # <input type="text" placeholder="type a number." id="Number" name="number" value=""/>
            <div class="weTrillMore"><small>*some text..</small></div>
            <div class="weTrillSubmit"> <button onclick="alert($('#Number').val());">Get</button></div>
        </div>

    </span>

</span>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.test').smallipop({
    preferredPosition: 'bottom',
    theme: 'blue',
    hideOnPopupClick: false,
    triggerOnClick:true,  
    hideDelay:10000,
    invertAnimation: true
});
```

The problem is I cant see the value with

```
$('#Number').val();
```

Comment: That's because it's not the same element, the plugin creates another element dynamically when the popup appears.

Comment: But in your jsfiddle, value of element #Number is empty, you got it if you set it: http://jsfiddle.net/R6Mqe/8/

Comment: @roasted Type something into the input and click the button.  It doesn't show the value you typed.

Comment: @Archer ha, thx, i see the problem now.

Comment: $('.smallipop-instance #Number').val() would do the trick

Comment: alert($('[id=Number]').length); returns 2 which means plugin clone elements with ID. I would avoid this plugin then or not set IDs for content elements

Comment: another question.. sorry 4 my noobness..:)
what should i do to make it work on iOS ? because when i focus the input, the tooltip closes..:O

Answer (score 3):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/R6Mqe/9/ is the code that worked for me. You have to watch for click event of the button and than traverse and fetch the input value.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    var val = $(this).closest('.weTrillForm').find('input').val();
    alert(val);
});
```